# Holes in ContourPlot3D

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization

I have a polynomial `polyHP`  and I put some conditions `Reg`  on it and I try to plot it with `ControurPlot3D`. Unfortunately, the resulting surface is full of holes.

[image: Resulting surface full of holes]

Can you please advise me how to render a surface without holes?

Edit: inserted definition of polyHP. Sorry, I forget to paste it.
`polyHP = ((x - 1)^2/5^2 - y^2/5^2 - (z + 5))`

````
Reg = x^2 <= 124 + 2 x + y^2 + 25 z && 
   200 x + 400 x^2 + 401 y^2 + 10040 z + 60 x z <= 50100 + 499 z^2 && 
   860 + 80 x^2 + 92 y^2 + 15 z^2 + 4 y (-94 + 9 z) > 
    8 x (70 + 2 y - 9 z) + 228 z && 
   23 - 254 x + 23 x^2 + 78 y^2 + 30 x z + 3 z^2 > 30 z && 
   27793 + 13 x^2 + 2673 y^2 + 2 x (253 + 8 y - 24 z) + 273 z^2 + 
     8 y (-2248 + 225 z) > 5508 z;
ContourPlot3D[polyHP == 0, {x, -15, 15}, {y, -15, 15}, {z, -15, 15}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Evaluate[Reg]], 
 RegionBoundaryStyle -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None, Mesh -> None]```
````

Comment: Please include (some) definition for `polyHP`.

Comment: Without definition of `polyHP` it's a bit hard to say anything, but probably your contour is intersecting or very close to the saddle surface defined by `x^2 <= 124 + 2 x + y^2 + 25 z` in `RegionFunction`, which results it being cut erratically on basis of internal algorithms used by `ContourPlot3D`. If you actually want to plot that surface, remove it from the region definition.

Comment: If your surface is actually above the saddle surface boundary you can try to increase `PlotPoints`. For a simplified toy example, consider `ContourPlot3D[x^2 == 124 + 2 x + y^2 + 25 z - .05, {x, -15, 15}, {y, -15, 15}, {z, -15, 15}, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 <= 124 + 2 x + y^2 + 25 z], PlotPoints -> 20, RegionBoundaryStyle -> None]`. Your plot looks a lot like what I get when these surfaces match exactly (remove `- .05`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to plot a contour which lies exactly on a region function boundary.

By some manual eyeballing one can recognise that `x^2 <= 124 + 2 x + y^2 + 25 z` in `Reg` is the saddle surface seen on the plot.

Is it actually the same surface as `polyHP`?

```
Resolve[
 ForAll[{x, y, z},
  Equivalent[
   polyHP == 0,
   x^2 == 124 + 2 x + y^2 + 25 z]],
 Reals]

(* True *)
```

Yes, it is. For every $x$, $y$ and $z$ these comparisons result a matching outcome.

Increasing `PlotPoints` might help if surfaces wouldn't overlap, but in this case I wouldn't bother trying.

You can simply drop the matching saddle surface condition from your `RegionFunction`, though:

```
polyHP = ((x - 1)^2/5^2 - y^2/5^2 - (z + 5));

Reg =(*x^2<=124+2 x+y^2+25 z&&*)
  200 x + 400 x^2 + 401 y^2 + 10040 z + 60 x z <= 50100 + 499 z^2 && 
   860 + 80 x^2 + 92 y^2 + 15 z^2 + 4 y (-94 + 9 z) > 
    8 x (70 + 2 y - 9 z) + 228 z && 
   23 - 254 x + 23 x^2 + 78 y^2 + 30 x z + 3 z^2 > 30 z && 
   27793 + 13 x^2 + 2673 y^2 + 2 x (253 + 8 y - 24 z) + 273 z^2 + 
     8 y (-2248 + 225 z) > 5508 z;

ContourPlot3D[polyHP == 0,
 {x, -15, 15}, {y, -15, 15}, {z, -15, 15},
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Evaluate[Reg]],
 RegionBoundaryStyle -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None, Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

Now remaining holes correspond to other constraints in `Reg`.

Comment: Thank you so much this was very helpful, I have been thinking about this for a several days.

Comment: @Kolda Good to know it helped! :)